# Using single else statement for multiple if conditions

Tags: if-statement, arduino

I am coding for an arduino project and i came across this problem, can anyone help me out!

```
if(condition1){
//my codes here
}
if(condition2){
//my codes here
}
if(condition3){
//my codes here
}
......
if(condition100){
//my codes here
}
else{
my codes here
}
```

I want to check all my if conditions, and execute the codes if the conditions are true, and run the else statement only if none of the if condition become true. 
Note that i cant use `else if` because i want to check all the if conditions, and if none are true i want to run the else
If conditions are not dependent on each other

Comment: How is this Python, C++ and Java, related ?

Comment: You can have a local boolean that is initially set to false, and that you change to true upon meeting a condition. The else can be replaced with an if that checks if this boolean is true.

Comment: You can keep an variable int and increment it in each if condition. then after the last condition, check it with number of if blocks you have.

Comment: yeah decide which language you want support...

Comment: Is [Pattern Matching](https://github.com/mpark/patterns) applicable here? Though it is still a proposal for C++23.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Boolean flag which is set in any of your `if`s.

```
bool noPathTaken = true;
if ( condition1 ) {
    noPathTaken = false;
    // ...
}
if ( condition2 ) {
    noPathTaken = false;
    // ...
}
// ...
if ( noPathTaken ) { // this would be your "else"
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

must set off all else flag in each test

```
bool elseFlag = 1;

if(condition1){
elseFlag = 0;
my codes here
}

if(condition2){
elseFlag = 0;
my codes here
}

if(condition3){
elseFlag = 0;
my codes here
}
......
if(condition100){
elseFlag = 0;
my codes here
}

if (elseFlag) {
 my codes here
}
```

because `else` gets binded only into preceding test operation, here `if(condition100) {`